# Can you access files api with service account?

Tags: office365, onedrive

I need to be able to access users one drives using a service account and impersonation. Is this possible with the office365 files api?

Answer (score 0):

Impersonation is the wrong word here when you're using Office 365 APIs. What's happening is that you are getting access to whatever data the user grants you permissions for -- so you can ask your app to request permissions like viewing & editing the user's files and folders, and then you'd pretty much have full access to the user's OneDrive account.

For more info, check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/application-manifest for permissions and scopes, and what they entail.

Comment: I need to access any users files within organization without consent. Google drive has this functionality with service accounts. Why can't I do this with One Drive.

Comment: To be clear you can do this today with Powershell from an admin account (search for sharepoint online powershell). But if you want to use the Office 365 APIs which request permissions through OAuth flow, you can't just access the user's data without any form of consent from the user

Answer (score 0):

I need to be able to access the files of users within the organization without consent or user passwords.